# Migrating VMWare vCenter Server 5.0.0.29542 to Another VM Win 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I'm looking to migrate VMWare vCenter Server 5.0.0.29542 from a win 2008 R2 server called W1 to another win 2008 R2 server called W2. Reason being we're looking to decommission W1. W1 is the vcenter manager and I do not want to shut down any of the production VMs in order to complete the migration. I was told this can be done using the VC the Linux appliance. I'm not sure how exactly. What's the best way to complete the migration with minimal downtime? We have vCenter Server 5 Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version, a Windows vCenter can be converted "on the fly" to a vCenter Appliance. This is also true for some migrations between appliance versions. Your vCenter is quite old, so you might need to do it in a couple of steps if you want to update all the way to vSphere 6.5.

Another option, if your vCenter isn't massively modified, is just to install a second appliance, and just join your ESXi hosts to the new vCenter. VMs are always unaffected by vCenter, they'll keep running just fine on the hosts themselves (as they would if your vCenter suddenly died), you'll just loose HA and a lot of other cluster level goodies while the vCenter is getting migrated/configured. You can also move an ESXi host with running VMs into a cluster without issues.